# Azure Active Directory B2C local accounts sign-up with profile picture

Tags: image, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, user-accounts, user-profile

Is it possible to upload the profile picture while user signs up with a local account? I've implemented with the built in claims but not sure how i can provide a picture at the time of signing up.

Answer (score 0):

In the signing up for the built-in policy, the user cannot upload a picture. Because in the user attribute, it only supports three data types: string, boolean and int.

[image]

And the input for the three data types doesn't have an option to upload a picture.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible with custom policy?